# Adding List Items to data grid view

Tags: vb.net

in one of my program I am scraping few data form web page  and adding it to list there are total seven list in which data get added  , and I want to add all seven list items to data grid view in different column I tried following code but only one row gets added to data grid

```
For Each link As HtmlNode In doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@class='job-title']")
    ans = link.InnerText
    list.Add(ans)
Next
For Each link1 As HtmlNode In doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//em[@class='advertiser-name']")
    ans1 = link1.InnerText
    list1.Add(ans1)
Next
For Each link2 As HtmlNode In doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='classification']")
    ans2 = link2.InnerText
    list2.Add(ans2)
Next

For Each link3 As HtmlNode In doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@class='listing-date']")
    ans3 = link3.InnerText
    list3.Add(ans3)
Next

For Each link4 As HtmlNode In doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@class='location']")
    ans4 = link4.InnerText
    list4.Add(ans4)
Next

For Each link5 As HtmlNode In doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@class='salary-range']")
    ans5 = link5.InnerText
    list5.Add(ans5)
Next

For Each link6 As HtmlNode In doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@class='job-title']")
    ans6 = link6.Attributes("href").Value
    list6.Add(ans6)

Next
    adddata()


Private Function adddata()
    Dim i As Integer
    Do Until list.Count = -1
        Form1.dgv.Rows.Add(list.Item(i), list1.Item(i), list2.Item(i), list3.Item(i), list4.Item(i), list5.Item(i), list6.Item(i))
    Loop
End Function
```

I am new to vb.net so please dont mind

Comment: Please post your sample XML. I think you are not doing it in the most efficient way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `adddata` function logic look a bit off. I think this is what you want :

```
Private Function adddata(ByVal list As List(Of String))
    Dim i As Integer = list.Count - 1
    Do Until i = -1
        Form1.dgv.Rows.Add(list.Item(i), list1.Item(i), list2.Item(i), list3.Item(i), list4.Item(i), list5.Item(i), list6.Item(i))
        i = i-1
    Loop
End Function
```

Call that function for each list you have (list, list1, list2, ...) passing the list as function's parameter.